# Inserting date into MySQL with variables declared

Tags: mysql, database

I have my table name mytest with ID as primary key and full name and approved_date columns in MySQL database

[image]

I need to insert the further 20 rows with every time a current `date + 1` value

here is the code

```
SET @X=1;
SET @myDate = CURDATE();


WHILE (@X<=20)

BEGIN

    INSERT INTO mytest(FullName,Approved_date)

    VALUES('Hello Maharjan', STR_TO_DATE(@myDate, '%Y-%m-%d'))

    SET @X= @X+1

    SET @myDate = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL @X DAY)

END
```

The query generate the error message

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
>      your  MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>
> 'WHILE (@X<=20)
>       BEGIN
>         INSERT INTO mytest(FULLName,Approved_date)
>         VALUE' at line 1

what is wrong with this code? its the simple query but I am not being able to 
 insert the data into myTest table with column name FullName and Approved_date .

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Comment: its my first time asking !! so please would you mind telling further which area I need to improve

Comment: You need to give us an actual problem description - _“bt i am not being able to insert”_ isn’t one. What happens? What errors do you get? (If you don’t know how to get error messages shown in the environment that you are using to submit this query to the database, then go research that first of all.)

Comment: Is your code in a stored program (procedure,function,trigger or event)?

Comment: no.. I am only executing it for one time thing !!

Comment: While loops are only allowed in stored programs in mysql.

Comment: Thank you P.Salmon. There was no any concrete answer with other individuals. I am new in mysql  Will work on other Loops !! thanks a lot :)